# Paypal Javascript SDK and billing agreement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, paypal

I am developing a web site, with React as frontend and my backend is Drupal, that is going to sell subscriptions. These subscribptions can have different prices over the time, ie: one subscription can cost today 20€ and next year 30€.
I have been reading on Paypal documentation, and this business model can be achieved with billing agreements and reference transactions, where the user agree to be billed in the
future.

I have read that Paypal has Subscriptions API, but I am not insterested in because my backend will be manage the recurring periods (I have more payment methods and I want to keep all of them with the same process).

Is it posible to implement billing agreements using the Javascript SDK? I know that the recurring payments (reference transactions) will be "launched" from my backend when the billing period expires.

Is there any example where I can see how to implement a Billing Agreement with Javascript?.

Thanks a lot.
Raul Serrano.

Answer (score 0):

If reference transactions is enabled on the receiving PayPal business account (something that requires business approval by PayPal's general support, not technical support) , you can then use either the classic API to create a billing agreement or equivalently one of the newer REST vault APIs to get a payment token. Then you'll be able to use that agreement/token to create transactions later, with your own recurrence engine.

The initial payer approval flow can be implemented with a normal [server-side-capture JS SDK integration](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server), optionally using `@paypal/react-paypal-js` to manage loading the SDK. The only difference compared to a normal one time payment checkout is that when the createOrder method will call your server to get an orderID/token that includes creating a billing agreement or vaulting, the SDK must have been loaded with [the vault parameter](https://developer.paypal.com/sdk/js/configuration/#link-queryparameters) set to true (so that it knows which payment method buttons can be available).